# Problems with my DNS and Nameservers after site move

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, website

I recently moved my website to a new host, and even after three days I can not access my site, all I could see was the "Moving Server" page that I left on the old server for my members to stay informed.

The majority of my members can access the site, and I've had two or three tell me they still get the old page and I can only access the website via a proxy or HotSpot shield.

There are the steps I took during the move:

1. Made a copy of site files
2. Put up the moving server page
3. Transferred files via FTP to the new server
4. Update nameservers at godaddy.com

To enable me and my other members to access my site, I logged into the cPanel at my old host and changed the DNS to point to the new server. Now we can access the site, however it obviously is only a temporary solution. I'm fairly new to this whole topic, and don't know how to fix this. Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

1. You should remove the old nameservers from the new authoritative name servers.  The new DNS servers shoul not have 'NS' records pointing anywhere else.
2. Provide both primary and secondary DNS servers to the domain registrar.
3. Some TTL values are too high.  This will not be a problem now that you have migrated, but best practice is to reduce TTL values to one hour or so (3600) about 10 days before moving.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however I'm unsure if I am I able to do this. I'm on a shared hosting plan so I'm not sure if this is available to me. I was only given the cs1 and cs2 nameservers. I've given them both to godaddy.

Comment: Have the old ones removed that are showing up in the report.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I lack knowledge in this completely. Who do I need to contact for this? My Current host, old host or domain registrar? Thanks again for your help. I really appreciate this.

Answer (score 0):

You can reach your present hosting provider's support to verify your Host records and Name server settings.